# Airflow Task has no start date , end date and duration

Tags: airflow

I'm a newbie in Airflow.
Does anybody know why the start date, end date of a task could be blank ?

Task Log Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Which version of Airflow do you use?

Comment: Hi Sergiy, Thank you for responding to my question. The airflow version that i use is 1.10.10 .

Comment: The task might be taking less than a second to execute completly.
More reference here - 
https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/23169